# Slow Response Time on Nop Commerce Admin Panel when multiple operators are working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, nopcommerce

We have nop commerce 2.3 for our live site, with appx. 100000+ products, 800 categories and 5000 Manufacturers.

It is a live site hosted on dedicated Server with Quad Core processor & 16 GB Ram.

While a team of 30 person is handling the site operation which includes adding new products, updating existing products and pictures, order processing, etc. Most of the time we are facing a lot of issue with the Administrator Panel of the Nop Commerce. Issues like sql time out are very common. And the admin panel speed is deadly slow, one person is able insert almost 8 products only on an average daily. Which is giving us a lot of pain.

To fix issue, we have hosted application on our local intranet server connected to live db server. But has the same issue. Just noticed that now live site is not having an issue while we work on the admin panel. But still there has been no real improvement on admin side when we work in admin panel. If just one person work on admin, then the site speed is good enough to support his operations, but for the team its just not sufficient.

What are your recommendations and suggested steps to improve this situation?

Comment: Please provide a list of known pages that you are finding slow. I will then run a load test and analyze any hotspots.

Comment: @PaulKnopf:Mostly products and categories pages from admin.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly to me this seems to be more of a database issue than anything else as one person can use it, but many can't. Have you spent anytime profiling for:

- poor performing queries
- deadlocks
- table or index scans
- missing indexes or index that are not used

That aside have you debugged through the admin application to isolate which calls within your admin app is experiencing these slow downs, in the event your performance issues are not db related?